# Reboot of Maeder's "Programming in Mathematica", an appeal

Tags: programming, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I have been using Mathematica since Version 1, and to me the touchstone for best practices in Mathematica is Roman Maeder's "Programming In Mathematica". It is not fair to say that PIM is dated, because every practice presented therein still works in Mathematica, which is a tribute to both Roman and Stephen. However, those of us who think of Mathematica as a programming language need instruction and guidance with the newer Paclet system, handled with the same care, completeness, and rigor that Roman gave us in PIM. Oh, and a user friendly documentation creation system, for which we are willing to wait. Briefly.

Wolfram developers: Please? Can we get "Programming in Wolfram Language"?

That said, where are the best resources currently available for best practices in Paclet authorship? Workbench and its documentation have not gotten any visible love lately. Todd Gayley's talk [Paclets and Paclet Development](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/tgayley/Published/PacletDevelopment.nb) is currently the best I have found, but it seems only an appetizer. We need something that ties the best of package development, packetizing, and distribution that Wolfram currently has to offer, including a chapter or two devoted to cloud-friendly distribution.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment of the first paragraph, but don't bury the lede about package development!  Thanks to lots of poking around and help from folks here I've got a paclet development workflow.  It's an unholy combination of multiple versions of MMA, Github, Wolfram Workbench, the DocTools palette (neither designed for user development), and some hacked scripts to fix the docs and upload them to Wolfram Cloud.  There's no single source of info.  Maybe people are holding off, because we've been promised a Wolfram Paclet Repository to lead us out of this dysfunctional ecosystem. Good luck!